# Angular Frequency about stable equilibrium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

So I have the potential energy defined as:
$$U(x)=U_0[2(\frac xa)^2-(\frac xa)^4]$$
And I want to find  the angular frequency of oscillations about the point of stable equilibrium.  I found the point of stable equilibrium to be 0, but now I do not know how to find the angular frequency.  Normally I would look to use 
$$E=K+U=\frac 12m \dot x^2+U(x)$$
But I do not know where an $\omega$ would end up popping out.

I a not looking for a solution, just a hint.

EDIT:: My attempt:

Using conservation of energy, I get that 
$$\frac 12 mv^2=U(a)=U_0$$
And then
$$\omega=kv=\frac {2\pi}{\lambda}\sqrt{\frac{2U_0}{m}}$$
Where $\lambda$=2a

Comment: What's your system describing a physical fact?

Comment: Where did you get $\omega=kv$? Why do you have $\lambda=2a$? Have a look at this question and see if it helps: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75411/frequency-of-small-oscillation-of-particle-under-gravity-constrained-to-move-in

Comment: The book of L. D. Landau on Classical mechanics has a section treating anharmonic oscillations, you could find it very useful for this problem. He aaproximates the periodic solution using Fourier series and then solves recoursively, you are dealing with an anharmonic potential. As a first approximation you would ignore the quartic term, for really small oscillations. The main point is that you cannot use a simple Taylor expansion around 0, the equilibrium point, without ignoring the quartic term, so you should resort to the method to treat anharmonic potential.