# Time period of an anharmonic but periodic motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, time, oscillators, anharmonic-oscillators

How do I find the time period of anharmonic motion given an expression of force as a function of $x$?

This is the question I was solving:

> $$ U(x)=k|x|^3 $$
>
> where $k$ is a positive constant. If the amplitude of the oscillation is $a$, then how is the time period $T(a)$ related to $a$?

Comment: The force $F(x)=-3kx^2$ is not always directed towards the centre. $x^2$ is always positive or zero, so the force always points to negative $x$. A particle subject to this force will just accelerate away in the $-x$ direction. Are you sure the potential wasn't $U = kx^4$ ?

Comment: The question is about a standard approach to solving such problems, without demanding explicitly to do the calculations. I think it is not off-topic (and with $|x|$ instead of $x$ the potential does have a minimum).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78415/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard approach for a conservative system is to write the full energy:
$$E= \frac{m\dot{x}^2}{2}+U(x),$$
which allows to express
$$\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{1}{\dot{x}}=\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{E-U(x)}}.$$ One can now integrate over half of a period, i.e. from the leftmost to the rightmost positions, defined by $U(x_L)=E, U(x_R)=E$:
$$\frac{T}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}\int_{x_L}^{x_R}dx
\frac{1}{\sqrt{E-U(x)}}.$$
In the case of a symmetric potential with a minimum at $x=0$ ($U(-x) = U(x)$), we can define the amplitude as $U(\pm a) = E$ and rewrite the last equation as
$$\frac{T}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}\int_{-a}^{a}dx
\frac{1}{\sqrt{U(a)-U(x)}}=
\sqrt{2m}\int_{0}^{a}dx
\frac{1}{\sqrt{U(a)-U(x)}}
.$$

Comment: Generally speaking, the period depends on the energy: if you don't know $E$, you cannot possibly know the period. Harmonic oscillator is a notable exception where the period is independent on the energy.