# Calculate period time from potential energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, time, anharmonic-oscillators

The question asks:

The potential energy of a particle in one dimensional space is:
$$
U = \frac{1}{2}Ax^2 + \frac{1}{4}Bx^4
$$

I need to calculate the period time, from the period calculate the frequency of small fluctuations.

---

#### What I thought: (didn't succeed)

I know that there are formulas like:
$$
\omega = \sqrt{U''(x)/m}
$$
But I don't know the mass and it seems that I need to first calculate the period time and not frequency.

Another direction I though of is:

$$
F = -\nabla U(x)
$$

And maybe I can think about the problem as harmonic oscillation, but again, I don't have the mass and ill find the frequency and not the period first.

Another way is looking at the total energy: $E = U + T \rightarrow U(x) + 1/2mx' $ and from here to get $x'$ and integrate between $-L$ to $L$ of the oscillation, yet I don't know the mass, $L$, or $E$.

---

So I don't know how to connect potential energy to the period of the system.

Comment: Here is a standard method for doing this: [Time period of a non-harmonic but periodic motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/547360/)

Comment: Yes, it good, thank you.

Comment: You might find my answer here to be interesting too [Calculating Frequency of Oscillations About a Stable Equilibrium Point](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/574614/157014).